# how do I upgrade symfony 1.3 to 2.x?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1

At work we use Symfony 1.3 and I want to upgrade to the latest version of symfony.

I saw this article:
[symfony upgrade 1.4](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/tutorial/1_4/en/upgrade)

That's a upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4 not verry helfull.

Can I download the latest symfony and create a new project and copy the folders from 1.3 like app, web, lib, config etc etc to my new version?

Ralph

Comment: I am sorry Ralph, you can't. You must rewrite your entire application.

Comment: 1.4 is still very usable. I would upgrade to it, but so far there's no security reason to abandon 1.4 and functionally it works very well.

Comment: yes I was wondering if I take a risk by hanging on to 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few differences between symfony1 and symfony2

You can read about the differences between the 2 on the [How Symfony2 Differs from Symfony1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/symfony1.html) docs page

Comment: Arrgghh bummer, I was hoping something like: install symfony 2 and copy/pastw some files. that's apparently not going to happen.
Thanks for the answer anyway :-) you to pabgaran